# Why g++ complains about "invalid declarator before", when passing callable object as argument?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

struct Callable {
  void operator()() {
    std::cout << "hello world\n";
  }
};

std::vector<std::function<void()>> cbs;

void register(std::function<void()>&& cb) {  // <-- ERROR
  cbs.emplace_back(std::move(cb));
}

int main() {
  Callable c;
  register(std::bind(std::ref(c)));
  for (auto& cb : cbs) {
    cb();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

In the above C++ snippet, `g++-9` reports error as `error: invalid declarator before 'cb'` on the line commented.

Why do I get this error? What does it mean, and how to fix it?

Comment: `register` is a keyword of c++.

Comment: [register](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/register) _automatic storage duration specifier (deprecated) (until C++17) The keyword is unused and reserved. (since C++17)_ As it may be there in legacy code they decided to keep it reserved. (That's actually bad because I often have to register things in my code and always scratch my head for the 2nd best name of such functions...)

Comment: @Scheff Actually there's a better reason that just accounting for legacy code. If there's a need for a new keyword in the future where `register` would be a reasonable name, we can just use that , instead of creating a new keyword :)

Comment: @cigien They didn't hesitate to introduce `override` as identifier with a special meaning at special positions so that it didn't become a reserved word. (A trick I used previously in my own compiler fiddlings so that this was not completely new to me.) So, I only half agree with you... ;-)

Comment: @Scheff Fair, but `override` is a contextual keyword, so it's much less important. Non-context keywords are much trickier. Take the extremely unfortunate case of `yield` having a `co_` in front of it :(

Comment: @Scheff Naming everything in another language than English (German for example like me), is a good way to avoid collisions like that. `register` would then become `registriere`, hence no collision.

Comment: @nada Sorry, no, never. :-) I don't like this mixed stuff. I have to bear with this in the daily radio news and advertising but I don't want to see it in my carefully written source code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message doesn't really help to spot the problem, but there's actually not much more the compiler could say. The issue is `register` is a reserved identifier. Just change the name of that function, and your code will work.

Comment: actually clang gives some more hints (https://godbolt.org/z/cEovfM), but gcc likes to stay cryptic here

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Oh, good point. The clang error is still useless, and the warning is because `register` is deprecated :p Change that to `void` for example and clang is completely unhelpful again.

Comment: fwiw with `-std=C++17` clangs warning is an error. And with gcc `-Werror -Wall` doesn't make it much better either. I guess its one of those mistakes that one makes not too often

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Yeah, exactly. In fact, I'm not comfortable with the CV for Typo that someone's already cast on the question.

Comment: hum, right I was dumb. This is the point when I know I have to take a break. I will rollback and clean comments here

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Not at all. Thanks for helping with the edits. BTW I see you changed your user name recently :) And yeah, let's clear up those comments.